# Python subprocess module sending path as string

Tags: python, python-3.x, ubuntu, terminal, zip

From a Python 3 script, I am zipping a folder.

The command which I would normally use in Terminal, and it **works**, is

`zip -P P4ssw0rd somefolder.zip somefolder/*`

(-P I use for password encryption, and the `/*` at the end because I want to zip the contents of the folder, if I don't include it the archive only contains an empty folder)

This successfully creates a **somefolder.zip** with the correct, password protected contents inside.

When I am executing this command from my script, I am using

`subprocess.call(['zip', '-P', 'P4ssw0rd', 'somefolder.zip', 'somefolder/*'])`

This gives me a zip error (the same kind that I would get if I wrote the command directly in Terminal, but if I misspelled the folder name, for example `zip -P P4ssw0rd somefolder.zip someOtherfolder/*`)

The warning says:

> zip warning: name not matched: somefolder/*

From my understanding, it somehow interpreting the / and the * as part of the folder's name, and not as me trying to navigate inside the folder...

Any ideas?

---

To make matters more confusing:

If the somefolder.zip already exists, then

`subprocess.call(['zip', '-P', 'P4ssw0rd', 'somefolder.zip', 'somefolder/*'])`

will execute. It says it is updating the contents of the folder, but really nothing changes as far as I can tell from the archive itself. However, if I change the `'somefolder/*'` to something else like `'someOtherfolder/*'`then it again throws a name not matched error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Upon further inspection, I found that `os.system()` proposed by @ImranD, although it works, is recommended to be replaced by the newer `supbrocess` module. So indeed the most correct way would be to use `subprocess.call()`, however the arguments should be provided in a different manner.

For example, in my original question, the correct (and working) way to use `subprocess.call()` would be as follows:

`subprocess.call('zip -P P4ssw0rd somefolder.zip somefolder/*', shell=True)`

In actuality, my line looks more like:

`subprocess.call('zip -P P4ssw0rd ' + archiveName + ' ' + folderToArchive, shell=True)`

where `archiveName` and `folderToArchive` are (I think pretty self-explanatory) strings which I have modified earlier.

Documentation:

> https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/subprocess.html#replacing-older-functions-with-the-subprocess-module

or more specifically:

> https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/subprocess.html#replacing-os-system

Answer (score 1):

If you don't mind using something else than the subprocess module, this works:

```
os.popen("zip -P P4ssw0rd somefolder.zip somefolder/*")
```

Of course, don't forget to `import os` beforehand.

Comment: It did not really work. It does create however weird files, with weird names and seemingly empty.

Comment: @celae What does exactly mean "weird"?

Comment: @P.Dmitry some file that has a random nonsense name. No extension. Seems to be empty

Comment: @celae Weird. Can you try using `os.system` instead of `os.popen` and tell me if it has the same behavior?

Answer (score 0):

it's probably because your script is being executed from a different location. try passing the absolute path instead of relative path.
e.g.

```
subprocess.call(['zip', '-P', 'P4ssw0rd', '-j', 'somefolder.zip', '/full/path/to/somefolder/*'])
```

Comment: It still says name not matched, apparently now it's interpreting the whole thing as a folder name.

Answer (score 0):

Probably you should manually convert glob `*` to list of files

```
dir = 'somefolder'
files = [ dir + f for f in listdir(dir) ]
cmd = ['zip', '-P', 'P4ssw0rd', 'somefolder.zip' ] + files
subprocess.call(cmd)
```